# MapReduce Output file is blank when trying to partition the dataset on some condition

Tags: java, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have a dataset which contains emoployee satisfaction level index,dept ,last evaluation, number of projects etc.From that file i have to find the average satisfation index of each dept.I have used a custom  partitioner which is dividing the dataset according to the number of dept and calculating their avg satisfaction index.For example i have 9 depts in the input file,so the job has created 9 files but none of the file contains any data, I haveno idea how to solve this .Here is mycomplete code and the dataset,

```
satisfaction_level,last_evaluation,number_project,average_montly_hours,time_spend_company,Work_accident,left,promotion_last_5years,sales,salary
0.38,0.53,2,157,3,0,1,0,sales,low
0.8,0.86,5,262,6,0,1,0,sales,medium
0.11,0.88,7,272,4,0,1,0,sales,medium
0.41,0.46,2,128,3,0,1,0,accounting,low
0.38,0.5,2,132,3,0,1,0,accounting,low
0.09,0.62,6,294,4,0,1,0,accounting,low
0.45,0.57,2,134,3,0,1,0,hr,low
0.4,0.51,2,145,3,0,1,0,hr,low
0.45,0.55,2,140,3,0,1,0,hr,low
0.84,0.87,4,246,6,0,1,0,hr,low
0.1,0.94,6,255,4,0,1,0,technical,low
0.38,0.46,2,137,3,0,1,0,technical,low
0.45,0.5,2,126,3,0,1,0,technical,low
................................  etc
```

Code

The mapper

```
public class AverageSatisfactionMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,FloatWritable>{


public void map(LongWritable key,Text value,Context context){

    String [] tokens = value.toString().split(",");
    try{
        Float satisfactionIndex = Float.parseFloat(tokens[0]);
        context.write(value, new FloatWritable(satisfactionIndex));
    }catch(Exception exception){
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

The Reducer

```
  public class AverageSatisfactionReducer extends Reducer<Text, FloatWritable, Text, Text>{

public void reduce(Text key,Iterable<FloatWritable> valueList,Context context){
    try{
        Float total = (float)0;
        int count =0;
        for(FloatWritable var:valueList){
            total+=var.get();
            System.out.println("reducer :"+var.get());
            count++;
        }
        Float avg = (Float)total/count;
        String out = "Total: " + total + " :: " + "Average: " + avg;
        context.write(key, new Text(out));
    }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The Partitioner

public class AverageSatisfactionPartitioner extends Partitioner{

```
@Override
public int getPartition(Text key, Text value, int numReduceTasks) {
    int partitionNo = 0;
    String [] tokens = value.toString().split(",");
    String dept = tokens[8];
    if(numReduceTasks!=0){
        if(dept.equals("sales"))
            partitionNo = 0;
        else if(dept.equals("accounting"))
            partitionNo = 1;
        else if(dept.equals("hr"))
            partitionNo=2;
        else if(dept.equals("technical"))
            partitionNo=3;
        else if(dept.equals("support"))
            partitionNo=4;
        else if(dept.equals("IT"))
            partitionNo=5;
        else if(dept.equals("product_mng"))
            partitionNo=6;
        else if(dept.equals("marketing"))
            partitionNo=7;
        else if(dept.equals("management"))
            partitionNo=8;
    }
    return partitionNo;
}

 }
```

The Driver class

```
public class AverageSatisfactionDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
    if (otherArgs.length != 2)
    {
        System.err.println("Usage: Employee Salary Anaysis <input> <output>");
        System.exit(2);
    }
    Job job = new Job(conf, "Employee Satisfaction Anaysis");
    job.setJobName("Custmom Patitioner");
    job.setJarByClass(AverageSatisfactionDriver.class);
    job.setMapperClass(AverageSatisfactionMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(AverageSatisfactionReducer.class);
    job.setPartitionerClass(AverageSatisfactionPartitioner.class);              //Set custom partitioner class

    job.setNumReduceTasks(9);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);


}

}
```

This is the output log of the job

```
18/04/23 14:16:54 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/04/23 14:17:42 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 13% reduce 0%
18/04/23 14:17:46 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 22% reduce 0%
18/04/23 14:17:49 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 30% reduce 0%
18/04/23 14:17:52 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 40% reduce 0%
18/04/23 14:17:55 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 54% reduce 0%
18/04/23 14:17:58 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 63% reduce 0%
18/04/23 14:18:00 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
18/04/23 14:18:47 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 7%
18/04/23 14:18:52 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 11%
18/04/23 14:19:03 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 19%
18/04/23 14:19:09 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 22%
18/04/23 14:19:16 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 33%
18/04/23 14:19:25 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 44%
18/04/23 14:19:29 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 52%
18/04/23 14:19:42 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 63%
18/04/23 14:19:45 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 67%
18/04/23 14:20:09 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 78%
18/04/23 14:20:11 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 89%
18/04/23 14:20:13 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
18/04/23 14:20:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1523849056360_0028 completed successfully
18/04/23 14:20:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 50
  File System Counters
    FILE: Number of bytes read=54
    FILE: Number of bytes written=1041435
    FILE: Number of read operations=0
    FILE: Number of large read operations=0
    FILE: Number of write operations=0
    HDFS: Number of bytes read=566904
    HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
    HDFS: Number of read operations=30
    HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
    HDFS: Number of write operations=18
Job Counters 
    Killed reduce tasks=3
    Launched map tasks=1
    Launched reduce tasks=12
        Data-local map tasks=1
    Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=63182
    Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=675539
    Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=63182
    Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=675539
    Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=63182
    Total vcore-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=675539
    Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=64698368
    Total megabyte-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=691751936
    Map-Reduce Framework
    Map input records=15000
    Map output records=0
    Map output bytes=0
    Map output materialized bytes=54
    Input split bytes=126
    Combine input records=0
    Combine output records=0
    Reduce input groups=0
    Reduce shuffle bytes=54
    Reduce input records=0
    Reduce output records=0
    Spilled Records=0
    Shuffled Maps =9
    Failed Shuffles=0
    Merged Map outputs=9
    GC time elapsed (ms)=31305
    CPU time spent (ms)=55940
    Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=763138048
    Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=3485786112
    Total committed heap usage (bytes)=268046336
    Shuffle Errors
    BAD_ID=0
    CONNECTION=0
    IO_ERROR=0
    WRONG_LENGTH=0
    WRONG_MAP=0
    WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Input Format Counters 
    Bytes Read=566778
    File Output Format Counters 
    Bytes Written=0
```

Please help me

Comment: Try changing job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class); to job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);

Comment: @COLDICE  changed ,not helping

Comment: In mapper class you are passing "value" as key to reducer, you need to pass department as key

Comment: Can you edit my code ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the parameter type in partitioner while extending

```
public class AverageSatisfactionPartitioner extends Partitioner<Text,Text>
```

Comment: have you change this 
job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class); to this job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);